How could this man be prosecuted for deleting naked pictures on his own phone?
From today's Washington Post:

Two Missouri law enforcement officers have been charged in separate federal cases this week with illegally searching the cellphones of women they encountered during traffic stops to steal their nude photos, the U.S. Attorney’s Office for the Eastern District of Missouri said.


Former Florissant police officer Julian Alcala, 29, was indicted by a grand jury and accused of illegally searching the cellphones of 20 women between February and May. He allegedly took their phones under the pretext of checking their insurance coverage or vehicle registration, searched the phones for nude pictures, and photographed the pictures with his phone, the indictment said, adding that he found an explicit video in one victim’s phone and texted it to his own cellphone, before attempting to delete evidence of the text.


A separate indictment accused former Missouri State Highway Patrol trooper David McKnight, 39, of similarly unlawfully searching nine women’s cellphones during traffic stops for nude photos and taking pictures of them with his personal cellphone. He later deleted the images from his cellphone, it says.


They both also face a charge of destroying records in a federal investigation — Alcala for allegedly deleting the text message evidence of the video he sent to himself from one woman’s phone, and McKnight for allegedly deleting the illegally obtained images from his phone.

How can it be illegal to delete something from your own telephone?

Destroying evidence in a federal investigation. In other words, destroying evidence of a serious  crime.

@ OK, but does the government have to notify you that your cell phone is under investigation? If you innocently delete something, and it turns out later that it was important to an investigation, are you liable? === I always assumed that you can do whatever you want with your own property.

The title of the question seems to be based on a misunderstanding of the quoted text. “(not 1 but) 2 guys” implies that both men were charged based on deleting data from their own phone, but the text you quote says that this is only one the case for McKnight. Alcala’s charge is based on deleting the text message evidence on the woman’s phone, not his own.

As clarified in the comments, the questioner is specifically concerned with a person unknowingly deleting materials that are relevant to an investigation.
The phrase "destroying records in a federal investigation" is not entirely unambiguous, but it most likely refers to a charge under 18 USC 1519 of the Sarbanes-Oxley Act, which reads as follows (emphasis added):

Whoever knowingly alters, destroys, mutilates, conceals, covers up, falsifies, or makes a false entry in any record, document, or tangible object with the intent to impede, obstruct, or influence the investigation or proper administration of any matter within the jurisdiction of any department or agency of the United States or any case filed under title 11, or in relation to or contemplation of any such matter or case, shall be fined under this title, imprisoned not more than 20 years, or both.

The prosecution is required to prove that the officers not only destroyed these text messages and photos, but also that they did so specifically for the purpose of obstructing or otherwise influencing the investigation. The officers may argue that they deleted these items for some other, innocent purpose, and that would be a defense to the charge. This is a fact question for a jury to determine, based on the totality of the evidence, including the nature of the deleted materials, the circumstances in which they were deleted, and any testimony the defendant may give in relation to those materials, if they choose to testify at all.
In my entirely subjective opinion, it is going to be very difficult to persuade the trier of fact to believe such a defense, especially if the defendants do not testify and there is no other exculpatory evidence. As with any criminal case, the standard of proof is beyond a reasonable doubt, but that does not mean that the jury is required to believe any defense that is not physically impossible. It merely means that the jury is required to determine whether there is "reasonable" doubt as to the defendants' guilt. See for example these model jury instructions from the Ninth Circuit, which explicitly state that a reasonable doubt is "not based purely on speculation."

If the officer had 1000 private photos and deleted them all, that's one thing. If he deleted the 20 with evidence that's destruction of evidence beyond reasonable doubt.

@gnasher729 It still depends on other factors, not least when he deleted them. He must have known that taking the photos was illegal, but if he deleted only these specific ones before he was aware of the investigation, it is not beyond reasonable doubt to claim that he did so because had eventually come to regret his actions (e.g., he showed them to someone who convinced him he’d acted unacceptably). Conversely, if he completely wiped his phone of all photos immediately after finding out he was being investigated, it would be hard to argue that’s not intentional destruction of evidence.
